# How to clean up dev/sda1 as it's full Using Airflow

Tags: disk

Am using Airflow, Yesterday i deleted airflow.scheduler.out through rm command, but the size has not deleted as it contains 81GB , i set an alert on prometheus tool, if goes above 80G, Alerts runs on.

Now, after deleteting airflow.scheduler.out rm the size remians same..

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have hidden trash on the disk?

Change directory to the root of the disk maybe something like:

```
cd /media/$USER/Airflow-Disk
```

Show all files, including those that hidden e.g., Trash

```
   ls -a
```

Delete the trash

```
 sudo rm -R .Trash*
```

Check disk space:

```
cd ../
du -h Airflow-Disk/
```